# Use Android phone camera to perform an action?

Tags: android, camera, implementation, sensors

I would like to know if it is possible to register a movement close to the camera, and then perform some actions inside an app.

This was possible on Symbian, so it should be also on newer Android-powered phones. The problem is I can't find any resource to get started with.

Does anybody have any ideas on where I should start?

Comment: Computer vision libraries, like OpenCV, are perhaps candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a library created over on Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/android-motion-detection/

If you want something a little more powerful, you can also run OpenCV on Android: http://opencv.org/android Don't think you will be able to do anything detecting the distance without another camera or a different type of sensor (like sonar) though.

As a bonus, depending on what your are trying to achieve, there's even a nice API doesn't involve anything additional to the Android SDK: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html